# How to deal with EventEmitter memory leaks in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js

In my js script, I am using the Readline method to take input from console.

My input is as follows:
An integer n, denoting the size of array A.
n number of space-separated integers denoting the array A.
An integer m, denoting the size of array B.
m number of space-separated integers denoting the array B.

I initiate the readline object using the following code:

```
var readline = require('readline');
var rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout,
  terminal: false
});
```

I use the following code to fetch these values:

```
rl.on('line', function (line) {
    var n = line;
    var A = new Array(n);

    rl.on('line', function (line) {
        A = line.split(" ");

        rl.on('line', function (line) {
            var m = line;
            var B = new Array(m);

            rl.on('line', function (line){
                B = line.split(" ");
                Solution(n, m, A, B);
            })
        })
    })
})
```

The code works fine, the Solution function is called properly, nothing unusual with that.
In the console, I get this warning; how to get rid of this:

> (node:12624) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 line listeners >added to [Interface]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit

Comment: I doubt this code "works". Have you counted *how often* `Solution(…)` is called?

Comment: @Bergi Yes I have checked, the solution function is called just once and the code works fine too; I put console.log(A) inside the solution function. I am just getting this error right after the print statement.

Comment: Oh, of course. Try passing more than 4 lines, then you'll see it.

Comment: How do I get rd of this error?

Comment: Use `once` instead of `on`, or try to avoid nesting in general. Maybe try using `async`/`await` if you can get a promise for the next line.

Comment: I solved it using a different approach altogether using process.

Answer (score 0):

To take input from the user in nodeJS I used a different and more convenient approach altogether.
I used ***process*** in nodeJS.

Here is the code,

```
function processData(input) {
    var array = input.split(/\s|\n+/);
    console.log(array);
} 

process.stdin.resume();
process.stdin.setEncoding("ascii");
_input = "";
process.stdin.on("data", function (input) {
    _input += input;
});

process.stdin.on("end", function () {
   processData(_input);
});
```

I ran it on IDEONE using NodeJS compiler and it works well.

IDEONE takes input from users before running the script, hence this code works as it detects where the input is ending. 
I still cannot figure out how to run this code in Visual Studio Code where the compiler cannot detect end of input.